# How does chrome automatically fix bad markup?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I was looking into a bug and noticed that Chrome automatically attempted to cleanup the bad HTML syntax. The offending line looked like:

```
<span>Hi there</span><a class="help-link"
```

As you can see, the anchor tag is not closed, but when I opened the page, it closed the anchor (although it added the tag for the following element between the open/close of the anchor), then it went through the rest of the code properly.

I was curious if there was any documentation on how chrome goes about trying to patch faulty markup on the fly like this? I tried searching for documentation, but wasn't able to come up with anything helpful.

Comment: That's a pretty minor feature considering the development of chrome is credited to a company that has basically infinite spending money.

Comment: True, but I'm curious what logic rules are in place. I'm more looking for documentation than pointing out a nifty feature.

Comment: I'm not sure they would publicly document something that could be used by competitors. I can think of how I would do it using string comparisons, regex, etc, in a back end process. Not specifically on the fly though.